# Stopping default scrolling behavior

Tags: jquery

I want to stop default scrolling behaviour on spacebar click. Furthermore, I also need to stop anchor tag redirection on the enter keypress. Below is the code to catch keypress event.

```
$j(".level1.haschildren a").focus(function(e){
  $j(this).keypress(function(e) {
    if ( e.keyCode === 13 || e.keyCode === 32 ) {
      e.preventDefault(); // This is not working

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: can you show us all necessary codes? (html,css) and also try `$j(this).siblings("ul").css({"opacity": 1.0, "visibility": "visible"});`

Comment: I have modified my question please review and provide your feedback.